# Copy entite fxml data to different container

Tags: javafx, copy, javafx-8, vbox

I am having two vbox(es).

First vbox fx:id is **vbox1**

Second vbox fx:id is **vbox2**

In vbox1 I am having textbox, combobox, buttons and everything else.

I am having one button which want to **copy**(onclick) entire source/fxml from vbox1 to vbox2.

Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Define the content of the `VBox`es in a separate FXML file. You can include the content in the first `VBox` directly in your "main" fxml with a `<fx:include>`:

```
<VBox fx:id="vbox1">
    <fx:include source="Content.fxml"/>
</VBox>
```

and then you can load another copy in the button's handler with

```
@FXML
public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent e) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Content.fxml"));
    vbox2.getChildren().add(loader.load());
}
```

Complete example (everything in a package called `application`):

Main.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainController">
    <center>
        <HBox spacing="5">
            <VBox fx:id="vbox1">
                <fx:include source="Content.fxml"/>
            </VBox>
            <VBox fx:id="vbox2"/>
        </HBox>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <Button text="Load" onAction="#load" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER"/>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

MainController.java:

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private VBox vbox1 ;
    @FXML
    private VBox vbox2 ;
    @FXML
    private void load() throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Content.fxml"));
        vbox2.getChildren().add(loader.load());
    }
}
```

Content.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>

<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <TextField promptText="Text Field"/>
    <ComboBox>
        <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                <String fx:value="One"/>
                <String fx:value="Two"/>
                <String fx:value="Three"/>
            </FXCollections>
        </items>
    </ComboBox>
    <Button text="Click me"/>
</VBox>
```

Main.java:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```